# Deserialize a XML to C# class from a wsdl

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

I am using a Web Service (wsdl), and I need to add a XML(that I receive) to my request, I added the web reference to Visual Studio and it generated a few classes.

I need to add a rDE instance to my request so I tried deserializing the XML using the generated classes, it doesn't throw an Exception but all the properties are null, I have been able to send the same XML through postman so the XML is ok, I don't know if I have the correct approach here since is my first time doing this.

These are the generated classes

```
    /// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.8.4084.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="*")]
public partial class rDE {
    
    private string dVerForField;
    
    private DE deField;
    
    private gCamFuFD gCamFuFDField;
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType="integer")]
    public string dVerFor {
        get {
            return this.dVerForField;
        }
        set {
            this.dVerForField = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    public DE DE {
        get {
            return this.deField;
        }
        set {
            this.deField = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    public gCamFuFD gCamFuFD {
        get {
            return this.gCamFuFDField;
        }
        set {
            this.gCamFuFDField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.8.4084.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="*")]
public partial class DE {
    
    private string dDVIdField;
    
    private System.DateTime dFecFirmaField;
    
    private bool dFecFirmaFieldSpecified;
    
    private string dSisFactField;
    
    private gOpeDE gOpeDEField;
    
    private gTimb gTimbField;
    
    private gDatGralOpe gDatGralOpeField;
    
    private gDtipDE gDtipDEField;
    
    private gTotSub gTotSubField;
    
    private gCamGen gCamGenField;
    
    private gCamDEAsoc[] gCamDEAsocField;
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType="integer")]
    public string dDVId {
        get {
            return this.dDVIdField;
        }
        set {
            this.dDVIdField = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    public System.DateTime dFecFirma {
        get {
            return this.dFecFirmaField;
        }
        set {
            this.dFecFirmaField = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool dFecFirmaSpecified {
        get {
            return this.dFecFirmaFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.dFecFirmaFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType="integer")]
    public string dSisFact {
        get {
            return this.dSisFactField;
        }
        set {
            this.dSisFactField = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    public gOpeDE gOpeDE {
        get {
            return this.gOpeDEField;
        }
        set {
            this.gOpeDEField = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    public gTimb gTimb {
        get {
            return this.gTimbField;
        }
        set {
            this.gTimbField = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    public gDatGralOpe gDatGralOpe {
        get {
            return this.gDatGralOpeField;
        }
        set {
            this.gDatGralOpeField = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    public gDtipDE gDtipDE {
        get {
            return this.gDtipDEField;
        }
        set {
            this.gDtipDEField = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    public gTotSub gTotSub {
        get {
            return this.gTotSubField;
        }
        set {
            this.gTotSubField = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    public gCamGen gCamGen {
        get {
            return this.gCamGenField;
        }
        set {
            this.gCamGenField = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("gCamDEAsoc")]
    public gCamDEAsoc[] gCamDEAsoc {
        get {
            return this.gCamDEAsocField;
        }
        set {
            this.gCamDEAsocField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.8.4084.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="*")]
public partial class gOpeDE {
    
    private string iTipEmiField;
    
    private string dDesTipEmiField;
    
    private string dCodSegField;
    
    private string dInfoEmiField;
    
    private string dInfoFiscField;
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType="integer")]
    public string iTipEmi {
        get {
            return this.iTipEmiField;
        }
        set {
            this.iTipEmiField = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    public string dDesTipEmi {
        get {
            return this.dDesTipEmiField;
        }
        set {
            this.dDesTipEmiField = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType="integer")]
    public string dCodSeg {
        get {
            return this.dCodSegField;
        }
        set {
            this.dCodSegField = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    public string dInfoEmi {
        get {
            return this.dInfoEmiField;
        }
        set {
            this.dInfoEmiField = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    public string dInfoFisc {
        get {
            return this.dInfoFiscField;
        }
        set {
            this.dInfoFiscField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my XML(Its Elements may vary, it can have more or less elements but this is the XML I have been using to test)

```
<rDE>
  <DE>
    <gOpeDE>
      <iTipEmi>1</iTipEmi>
    </gOpeDE>
    <gTimb>
      <iTiDE>1</iTiDE>
      <dNumTim>14601619</dNumTim>
      <dEst>9</dEst>
      <dPunExp>9</dPunExp>
      <dNumDoc>22712</dNumDoc>
    </gTimb>
    <gDatGralOpe>
      <dFeEmiDE>12/04/2022</dFeEmiDE>
      <gOpeCom>
        <iTipTra>1</iTipTra>
        <iTImp>1</iTImp>
        <cMoneOpe>PYG</cMoneOpe>
      </gOpeCom>
      <gEmis>
        <dRucEm>800486946</dRucEm>
        <dDVEmi>4</dDVEmi>
      </gEmis>
      <gDatRec>
        <iNatRec>1</iNatRec>
        <iTiOpe>1</iTiOpe>
        <dRucRec>5307630</dRucRec>
        <dDVRec>3</dDVRec>
        <iTiContRec>1</iTiContRec>
        <dNomRec>BARRETO MENDEZ EDER MATIAS</dNomRec>
        <dDirRec>A</dDirRec>
        <dNumCasRec>0</dNumCasRec>
        <cPaisRec>PRY</cPaisRec>
        <dDesPaisRe>Paraguay</dDesPaisRe>
      </gDatRec>
    </gDatGralOpe>
    <gDtipDE>
      <gCamFE>
        <iIndPres>1</iIndPres>
      </gCamFE>
      <gCamItem>
        <dCodInt>614143297809</dCodInt>
        <dDesProSer>R CAPELETIS - POLLO 500GR PAQ </dDesProSer>
        <dCantProSer>3.00</dCantProSer>
        <gValorItem>
          <dPUniProSer>12500</dPUniProSer>
          <dTotBruOpeItem>37500</dTotBruOpeItem>
          <gValorRestaItem>
            <dDescItem>0</dDescItem>
            <dTotOpeItem>37500</dTotOpeItem>
          </gValorRestaItem>
        </gValorItem>
        <gCamIVA>
          <iAfecIVA>1</iAfecIVA>
          <dTasaIVA>10</dTasaIVA>
        </gCamIVA>
      </gCamItem>
      <gCamCond>
        <iCondOpe>1</iCondOpe>
      </gCamCond>
    </gDtipDE>
    <gTotSub>
      <dSubExe>0</dSubExe>
      <dSub5>0</dSub5>
      <dSub10>37500</dSub10>
      <dTotOpe>37500</dTotOpe>
      <dRedon>0</dRedon>
    </gTotSub>
  </DE>
</rDE>
```

This is where I deserialize

```
        public rDE deserializeXML(string xml) 
    {
        rDE obj = new rDE();
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(rDE));
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        obj = (rDE)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        return obj;
    }
```